# Bigquery date interval syntax

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How would I do the following in BigQuery?

```
date in (now() - interval 1 day, now() - interval 2 day)
```

Basically, I want to get the following:

```
date IN ("2020-05-18", "2020-05-17")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date in (DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about direct comparisons:

```
date >= date('2020-05-17') and
date <= date('2020'05-18')
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
date in (date('2020-05-17'), date('2020'05-18'))
```

Comment: that's fine, but it should be dynamic, i.e., use a datediff/dateadd function if that exists there.